# LINQ query for retrieving items that contain any value from a list?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Let's say I have a table containing reports, and each report has an Employee ID for the employee assigned to it.

Let's also say I have a list of employee ID, like:

```
[ "1001", "1002", "1003", "1004", "1005", "1006", "1007"]
```

What LINQ query will return all the reports that have those employee IDs? If it were just a single criteria (like if I wanted everything older than a year), I could just do

```
query.Where(report => report.LaunchedDate < lastYear)
```

But how do I do it for when I have many items? Do I need to use a loop or is there a LINQ method for enumerating the list of employee IDs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for something along the lines of:

```
var employeeIds = ["1001", "1002", "1003", "1004", "1005", "1006", "1007"];

query.Where(report => employeeIds.Contains(report.EmployeeId));
```